# How to bind hashtable with listbox

Tags: asp.net

Iam belinda. now only i learn the asp.net controls.. I have tried the following code. But i got an error..

I have used a code to bind the hashtable with listbox but i cant.

Anyone please help me to understand the hashtable  and the bind concept clearly...

.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Hashtable.aspx.vb" Inherits="Hashtable" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox><br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.vb:

```
#Region "Namespaces"

Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail

#End Region
Partial Class Hashtable
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ht As New Hashtable
        ht.Items.Add("1", "Sunday")
        ht.Items.Add("2", "Monday")
        ht.Items.Add("3", "Tuesday")
        ht.Items.Add("4", "Wednesday")
        ht.Items.Add("5", "Thursday")
        ht.Items.Add("6", "Friday")
        ht.Items.Add("7", "Saturday")

        ListBox1.DataSource = ht
        ListBox1.DataValueField = "Key"
        ListBox1.DataTextField = "Value"
        ListBox1.DataBind()


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the exact error - please update you question to allow others to help you better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible to databind to a hash table.

Something like this should work

```
Hashtable myHashTable = new HashTable();
myHashTable.Add ("First", "The first item");
myHashTable.Add ("Second", "The second item");
myHashTable.Add ("Third", "The third item");


ddlMyDropDownList.DataSource = myHashTable.Keys;
ddlMyDropDownList.DataBind();
```

In Your Code Here:

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ht As Hashtable = New Hashtable(7)
    ht.Add("1", "Sunday")
    ht.Add("2", "Monday")
    ht.Add("3", "Tuesday")
    ht.Add("4", "Wednesday")
    ht.Add("5", "Thursday")
    ht.Add("6", "Friday")
    ht.Add("7", "Saturday")

    ListBox1.DataSource = ht
    ListBox1.DataValueField = "Key"
    ListBox1.DataTextField = "Value"
    ListBox1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Hi nayeem, iam getting the folllowing bugError 1 Type 'BindingSource' is not defined.

Comment: Please check my updated code and let me know if there are any issue

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use the old Hashtable class, use the replacement Dictionary instead. The same is true for (almost) all classes from the System.Collections namespace.

though you can try

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ht As New Hashtable
        ht.Items.Add("1", "Sunday")
        ht.Items.Add("2", "Monday")
        ht.Items.Add("3", "Tuesday")
        ht.Items.Add("4", "Wednesday")
        ht.Items.Add("5", "Thursday")
        ht.Items.Add("6", "Friday")
        ht.Items.Add("7", "Saturday")

       foreach (var item in ht)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Value)
    }


    End Sub
```